# What are the eigenvalues of a squared matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, generalized-eigenvector

Suppose matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.
Are the eigenvalues of $A^2$: $\lambda_1^2$ and $\lambda_2^2$?
If so, can I prove this by simple diagnolization, where $T$ is the eigenbasis and $T^{-1}$ its inverse and simply because $T^{-1}A^2T$ equals the identity matrix stretched by corresponding squared eigenvalues so eigenvalues of $A^2$ are squared eigenvalues of $A$?
Also, can this be generalized into $A^n$?

Comment: Note that $A$ might not be diagonalizable if it is larger than $2\times 2$ or if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$.

Comment: Suppose $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Then $A^2x = A(Ax) = A(\lambda x) = \lambda (Ax) = \lambda\cdot \lambda x = \lambda^2 x$.  No need to invoke diagonalization arguments

Comment: Terminology note: a *square* matrix is one with the same number of rows as columns. You might call this a *squared* matrix.

Comment: @JMoravitz, you are right, thanks.

Comment: @eyeballfrog indeed for the 1st part. But $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ is not a problem. For example, identity matrix has a single (double) eigenvalue $1$, and is so diagonalizable, that it is diagonal :D

Comment: @chrslg Identity matrix yes. Shear matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ not so much.

Comment: @eyeballfrog. Yeah, that one is not diagonalizable. But I thought (wrongly, obviously) you were claiming that if λ₁=λ₂ then A is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Note, tho, that $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and both matrix have a unique and single eigen-value, that is 1; so it is not really a counter example to the invalid rule "eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ squared" anyway (but it is a counter example to the OP proof).

Comment: It is easy to see the following: $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$ $\implies$ $\lambda^2$ an eigenvalue of $A^2$. The direction that seems more difficult and more interesting--at least to me!--is: $\lambda^2$ an eigenvalue of $A^2$ $\implies$ $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @Mike, yes, my point exactly. Except that the answer is straigthforward. "λ eigenvalue of A ⇒ λ² eigenvalue of A²" is true and obvious, as you said. "λ² eigenvalue of A² ⇒ λ eigenvalue of A" is not just difficult and interesting: it is simply false. That is not true of all A and all vectorspace (see my counter example. And, sure, if you choose ℂ as scalar field for your vectorspace, then, my counter example doesn't work. But if you choose ℝ as scalar field it work. And a counter example doesn't need to work every time. It just needs to work in a single case to be a counter example)

Comment: @JMoravitz: You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @chrslg I think this problem becomes interesting only when we consider algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @Mike Yes indeed, if you restrict the question to algebraically closed fields, it is less obvious whether "λ² eigenvalue of A² ⇒ λ eigenvalue of A" is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter example. In ℝ-space ℝ⁴, Consider the matrix

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

It has two eigenvalues, $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=2$.

Now compute $A^2$
$$
A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which has three eigenvalues, $\mu_1 = \lambda_1^2 = 1$, $\mu_2 = \lambda_2^2 = 4$ and $\mu_3=-1$.

So, no, eigenvalues of $A^2$ are not just the squares of eigenvalues of $A$.

(But the squares of eigenvalues of $A$ are all eigenvalues of $A^2$. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\exists u, Au=\lambda u$, and then $A^2 = A.Au = A\lambda_u = \lambda Au = \lambda \lambda u = \lambda^2 u$. But that is not the same result as "eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, squared")

As for your proof, it contains the words "eigenbasis". It is therefore valid only if there is an eigenbasis. It is only the case if $A$ is diagonalizable (which, by definition, means that it exists a basis made of eigenvectors). My counter example was carefully so that it is not diagonalizable (it is just a combination of a diagonal, and of a classical $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 &0\end{pmatrix}$ antipattern for diagonalization).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142613/discussion-on-answer-by-chrslg-what-are-the-eigenvalues-of-a-squared-matrix); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.